# How can I use a custom refresh indicator in a FlatList in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I want to replace the "refresh indicator" that is used in FlatList, etc. inside the RefreshControl. I am aware that there are some minor styling changes you can make with `tint` and `colors` to adjust the colors of the spinners on iOS and Android but I want to make my own spinner indicator entirely and disable the native spinners.

Is it possible to either disable the native spinners used during the refresh operation, or to replace them with my own custom spinners?

Answer (score -1):

This is challenging, especially given that most of the params are platform specific.  I've found that setting a high negative height has the effect of hiding the refresh indicator.

```js
<RefreshControl refreshing={refreshing} onRefresh={onRefresh} progressViewOffset={-500}/>
```